# Calling "gnuplot" from within ghci corrupts the terminal. Is it possible to restore it?

Tags: haskell, ghci

For example, see this session:

```
Prelude> import System.Process
Prelude System.Process> system "gnuplot filename.gnu"
Prelude System.Process>
```

Now, whenever I type at the terminal, nothing appears.  (Strangely, input is still being read in like normal.  You can type a command, press enter, and the results will appear.)  I have to restart ghci in order to get it working again.

Is there some command I can call that will reset ghci without restarting it?  Alternatively, is there a better way to call gnuplot so that it doesn't interfere?

Edit: this is ghc 7.6.2

Comment: I'm not sure because apparently you get a new prompt already, but you should get the terminal back when gnuplot exits, anyway, you can try `system "gnuplot filename.gnu &"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Prelude> import System.Process
Prelude System.Process> system "gnuplot filename.gnu"
Prelude System.Process> system "reset"
```

Usually the `reset` command can be found here:

```
$ which reset
/usr/bin/reset
```